# My SELECT form element is dying when created by JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm having a tough time figuring out what the issue is here, I have created form elements with JavaScript before and they worked, this is my first time doing a select.  Here is the page in question:

[Part 1](http://www.negativeworld.org/content.php)

So basically when "comic" is picked using the "type" select box there, JavaScript creates a new select box.  Here is the JavaScript:

```
function contentchange(changeit) {  
if(changeit.value=='comic')
{ 
    document.getElementById("extrafield1").innerHTML='<img src="design/espaceur.gif" width="12" height="1">Webcomic';
    document.getElementById("extrafield2").innerHTML="<img src='design/espaceur.gif' width='10' height='1'><select name='cf' id='cf' class='basic_box'><option value='1'>The Cloud Chasers</option></select>";
}
else
{ 
    document.getElementById("extrafield1").innerHTML=""; 
    document.getElementById("extrafield2").innerHTML="";
} }
```

And here is where it is put on my page:

```
<div id="extrafield2">
        <?php if ($filter_type == 'review' || $filter_type == 'game') { ?>
        <img src="design/espaceur.gif" width="10" height="1"><select name="pf" class="basic_box" id="pf">
                    <?php nintendocodes("platform", "nintendo", $filter_platform, false, "All"); ?> 
                    </select>
        <?php } else if ($filter_type == 'comic') { ?>
        <img src="design/espaceur.gif" width="10" height="1"><select name='cf' id='cf' class='basic_box'><?php comiccodes($filter_comic); ?></select>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

So, it is working as far as creating the select.  But for some reason when I submit on the form, it doesn't "take".  I'm using the same code for the select that I use on the page itself (you can see it here):

[Part 2](http://www.negativeworld.org/content.php?&tp=comic)

And it works fine there.  Basically I have no idea why this select isn't working.  I'm pretty sure the select itself is fine, it shows up fine through the JavaScript, it just doesn't "take".

Help?

Comment: Oh, I should mention, it DOES work for me on Internet Explorer, just not Firefox or Chrome.  Which is the opposite of how things usually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<form action="content.php" method="get">
...
</form>
</table>
```

Use

```
<form method=get action=content.php>
<table border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
..
</table>
</form>
```

You code isn't valid ( http://validator.w3.org/ ) and it seems it affects functionality in some browsers.

Comment: This is correct. I constructed a simple test and verified that OP's form works as expected with valid HTML.

Comment: I tried that with the saved page of author. But it needs to be proved online.

Comment: Yep that did it.  I can't believe I beat my head against the wall on this for hours!  Thanks!